# Vuetify checkboxes are prechecked when getting data from Vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vuetify.js

I have a problem with Vuetify checkboxes and Vuex.
What I want: Checkboxes are not check, an when any box is checked, the person-object is pushed to the selected-array. That is how it works in the [Vuetify docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selection-controls#examples).
The checkboxes are checked even though are they v-modelled to an empty arrray. The table with checkboxes are populated via a getter in a computed value and to first get data into the state, I dispatch an action in the created lifecycle. 
In the beginning when I just used static data, the checkboxes and other functions worked fine, but when I started using async data from Vuex, the checkboxes started being prechecked.
If I comment out the dispatch command in the created lifecycle, the checkboxes are not prechecked. Of course the table wont have data from the getter if the state in Vuex doesnt have data. But if I go to another page where the dispatch has been issued and go back to the table page, the getter now gets the data from state and checkboxes are not prechecked.

Anyone got a clue of why this is happening?

```js
<template>
  <v-simple-table>
    <template v-slot:default>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th @click="selectAll">Select</th>
          <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="(person, index) in getPersons" :key="index">
          <td>
            <v-checkbox v-model="selected" :value="person"></v-checkbox>
          </td>
          <td>{{ person.firstName }}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </template>
  </v-simple-table>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  created() {
    this.$store.dispatch("activePersons");
  },
  data() {
    return {
      selected: []
    };
  },
  computed: {
    getPersons() {
      const data = [
        {
          firstName: "John"
        },
        {
          firstName: "James"
        }
      ];
      console.log(data);
      let test = this.$store.getters.getList;
      return test;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    selectAll() {
      if (this.selected.length == this.getPersons.length) {
        this.selected = [];
      } else {
        this.selected = this.getPersons;
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
</style>
```

Comment: I think that you should use `:true-value` instead of `:value` - otherwise it interferes with the `v-model` which is just a syntactic sugar for `:value="model" @input="model = $event.target.value"`